# How to add 1234 1234 base 16 to MIPS Registers?

Tags: mips

I know how to add 1234 to a register in MIPS. For this I basically use `ADDI r1, r0, 1234`. However, I cannot figure out how to add 1234 1234 to a register. I think it overflows.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no single instruction. Rather, load the immediate value using the [common idiom](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/load32.html) into another register. Thus, your code looks something like:

```
LUI r2, 1234
ORI r2, r2, 1234
ADD r1, r0, r2
```

Comment: If you use ADDI, watch out for the sign extension if the top bit of the lower sixteen is set.